# Bochner integral of a function in $L^2$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, banach-spaces, bochner-spaces

This might be obvious, but I don't see why...

> Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{R}_+$ and $m(x) = \lambda/(\lambda - e^x)$. If $f \in L^2$, then
>
> $$
> mf = \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{\lambda e^x}{(\lambda - e^x)^2} \, f \chi_{(-\infty, x)} \, dx
> $$
>
> as a **Bochner** integral in $L^2$.

How could one derive the above equality?

Comment: You have $x$ being used as both a parameter of the left hand side and the variable of integration, something needs fixing for the expression to even make sense.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my post. (The present version is copied from a paper I'm reading.)

Comment: Did you mean $f\left(\chi_{(-\infty, x)}\right)$ or $f(x)\chi_{(-\infty, x)}$ ?

Comment: Math1000: not entirely sure, to be honest. Any idea which of those makes more sense?

Comment: Perhaps if you link to the paper this would easier to resolve

Comment: https://goo.gl/7i6VKb

(Proof of Theorem 2.4, p. 96.)